# Browse for folder dialogs only showing user directory

Tags: windows-7

I've recently noticed several applications where any "Browser for folder" dialogs they generate only show "Desktop" and my user directory.  They don't even show the folders on my desktop, just the desktop itself.  The most recent application to do this was Google Drive, when selecting a destination for its download folder.

In these situations I am unable to change drives or anything.  The only solution I found was to use mklink to make a hardlink to the folder I wanted inside my user directory, but this isn't a great solution.

I've run "scf /scannow" but that didn't return any errors.  Also I am an administrator user on my computer.

Is this an issue with my system, or are these applications arbitrarily limiting their browse dialogs to my user folder?

For reference, I'm running Windows 7 Pro x64.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is quite old, but i just found solution, which is ridiculous, but works, clean up Your desktop. This happens when there are to many files on desktop. Stupidest bug ever.

Comment: Is there any indication of how many is too many?

Comment: I had 308 items. I moved 216 items to another folder and everything fixed itself instantly.

Comment: This happened to me on Win11, all updates installed on this day, 2022.09.16! Thanks for  this! Was going crazy!